# Syntax error on the colon in an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python, and am making a sort-of game as one of my first projects that guesses a number between 1 and 10, then the user guesses it. They have three guesses, and the program tells the user if they need to go higher or lower on their next guess. The part of the code with the error in isn't crucial, as it only makes a guess not be wasted if the user puts in the same answer twice, allowing them to redo their guess the first time but not allowing a re-take the second. On the code, I have marked where the problem is. Like I said, I am really new to python and this is probably some amateur noobie mistake. Thanks in advance.

```python
import time # This imports the time module.
import random # This imports the random module.

MyNumber = random.randrange(1,10) # This picks a number for the variable 'MyNumber'

firstGuess = int(input('Ok then, we shall begin! What is your first guess?'))
print()
if firstGuess == (MyNumber):
 print('Well done! You win!')
 time.sleep(3)
 exit()
if firstGuess < MyNumber:
 print('Go Higher!')
 time.sleep(1)
if firstGuess > MyNumber:
 print('Go Lower!')
 time.sleep(1)

print()
secondGuess = int(input('Better luck this time! What is your second guess?'))
print()
if secondGuess == firstGuess:
 print('You tried that one last time! Don\'t worry, I won\'t count that one!')
 bungled = (1)
 secondGuess = int(input('What is your second guess?')
 if secondGuess == firstGuess:  # This colon is causing the problem. <===========
  print('You\'ve already tried that one twice!')
  bungled = (2)
if secondGuess == MyNumber:
 print('Well done! You win!')
 time.sleep(3)
 exit()
if secondGuess < MyNumber:
 print('Go Higher!')
 time.sleep(1)
if secondGuess > MyNumber:
 print('Go Lower!')
 time.sleep(1)

print()
thirdGuess = int(input('This is your final chance! What is your third guess?'))
print()
if thirdGuess == MyNumber:
 print('Well done! You win!')
 time.sleep(3)
 exit()
if thirdGuess < MyNumber:
 MyNumber = str(MyNumber)
 print('Sorry! You lost! The number was '+MyNumber)
 time.sleep(1)
 exit()
if thirdGuess > MyNumber:
 MyNumber = str(MyNumber)
 print('Sorry! You lost! The number was '+MyNumber)
 time.sleep(1)
 exit()
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's not actually the colon. It's the unclosed bracket on the previous line.

When you get a weird `SyntaxError`, check for bracket balance before it.

Comment: Thanks, I will always check the brackets when I get a weird error like that again.

Comment: Thanks alot, now I understand that the bracket balance is looking for a new bracket, but instead finds a `colon` on the next line, and **python just gives us the line at which it encounters the error and not the line on which the error is occurring!**

Comment: Well, python allows line breaks within parenthesis and brackets, so it does not know that you did not intend to make one; you may be lucky though, python 3.11 introduces better tracebacks for all exceptions, so they might count those buggers and give better messages now. ;)

Answer (score 4):

The line above is missing a parenthesis.
Change

`secondGuess = int(input('What is your second guess?')`

to

`secondGuess = int(input('What is your second guess?'))`

Comment: Thanks very much, I am not sure why the checkers did not pick that up. Everything works perfectly now :)